# updating attributes of a custom class using URLsession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I have the following problem I couldnt solve, maybe because I dont understand urlsessions well enough. So I have a mysql database and a php script that can get certain values of the database. I defined my own simple class that has certain attributes which are from the table in mysql and I defined a method in that custom class that retrieves this data and assigns these retrieved values to the object. My code that does this is as follows (probably many inefficiencies in my code...) which I tried in a playground file in Xcode, the class is called foodClass (since the database is about food):

```
import UIKit

class foodClass {
    var description : String?
    var price : Float?

    func downloadDish(){
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/downloadDishes.php")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //example id, which tells php which food to pick
        let postString = "id=\(12)"
        let utf8PostString = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: utf8PostString){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("no connection maybe?")
                }
            }
            else {
                if data != nil {
                    do {
                        let dishJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! NSDictionary
                        let disharray = dishJSON["dishes"] as! NSArray
                        //print to make sure that we get a response
                        print(disharray[0])
                        let tempdish = disharray[0] as! NSArray
                        self.description = tempdish[2] as! String
                        self.price = (tempdish[3] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 4.99

                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}


//test it out
var dish = foodClass()

dish.downloadDish()

print(dish.description)
```

So the print statement "print(disharray[0])" shows exactly what is in the database, so nothing is going wrong in retrieving data from the database. But somehow the attributes description and price do not get initialized after I call the function downloadDish(). Maybe I dont understand something crucial about classes and URLsessions.

Comment: Threading maybe?  Which prints first, `disharray[0]` or `description`?

Comment: @PhillipMills description prints first (it is nil) and then disharray[0]. Hmm that is weird. Why does that happen?

Comment: @PhillipMills how can I prioritize the retrieving of the data over printing description?

Comment: Your session task is asynchronous and the block you've defined for it executes when the task completes.  So, in a real program, you wouldn't want to do anything with the dish until after it's initialized by the block.

Comment: It's not a case of priority, but rather of waiting until the network process is finished.

Comment: @PhillipMills I added a "sleep(5)" before print(dish.description), assuming this is long enough that the network process will finish, but it still outputs nil, the printing order is now reversed though.

Comment: @PhillipMills my mistake, it actually works now!

Comment: It's easier to handle in an app than a playground.  Typically, your completion handler would end by telling your data model to update or dispatching something onto the main queue to update the UI.  The code that caused the session to execute wouldn't be waiting around for the result.